# What are the organic reactions that are taking place in this reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis, carbonyl-compounds, elimination

I know that **A** is the product of a Knoevenagel condensation between the aldehyde and the diethyl malonate, due to the acidic protons of the latter, but I don't know what the reaction between that product and potassium cyanide would be.

[image]

Comment: The are only 2 possible sites of nucleophilic attack on A for CN-. One attack is completely reversible and represents a dead end, so it must be the other.

Comment: I'm guessing then that you're referring to a nucleophilic attack on the double bond, because the attack on the ester would be pointless. That was one of my first thoughts, but I discarded that option because I didn't know where to get the proton that was missing, maybe from the solvent? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: The 1,4 attack on the double bond is the pointless one. Think through attack on one of the ester carbonyls

Comment: @Zenix  not as I see it. C is the cinnamic acid and D is the mixed anhydride.

Comment: @Waylander correct me, C is p-cyclohexyl cinnamic acid (after decarboxylation of geminal di-carboxylic acid). Thus, D will be mixed anhydride, what will AlCl3/CH2Cl2 do?

Comment: I would suggest OP to edit the title of question. As it stands, the title looks vague. Be specific with the title. A title should always reflect the body of question. Check this [meta post](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364/when-we-should-edit-the-title-of-a-question) to see what to write in a title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what I think is going on:

1. $Step$ $1$: As the OP correctly identified is a Knoevenagel condensation to give A diethyl 4-cyclohexyl-benzalmalonate.
2. $Step$ $2$ is an example of little-used ester hydrolysis using cyanide ion to give initially the acyl cyanide which is unstable in aq EtOH and gives the diacid B
3. $Step$ $3$ is loss of one carboxy group by acid catalysed decarboxylation to give the cinnamic acid C
4. $Step$ $4$ formation of the mixed anhydride D
5. $Step$ $5$ cyclisation through formation of an aluminium-acyl complex [literature example here](http://orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV2P0081) to give the final product 6-cyclohexyl-Inden-1-one E

[image]

Comment: Mechanism of step 5?

Comment: Formation of an acyl-aluminium complex similar to acyl halide/AlCl3 cyclisation. I've edited to include a reference. Not the way I would choose to do it (PPA would be my choice), but I think this question is trying to show alternative ways this could be done

Answer (score 4):

@Waylander has provided a well-reasoned solution to the post. I offer a different interpretation. Knoevenagel product **1a** has been converted in high yield to cyano ester **2a** and subsequently hydrolyzed to phenylsuccinic acid (**3a**) <sup>[1](http://orgsyn.org/Default.aspx)</sup>.  In the addition of cyanide to the double bond of **1a** and protonation, one of the labile ester groups is cleaved by cyanide. (e.g., Diethyl malonate is readily monosaponified by base in the cold.) Cyclization of anhydride **4a** has been accomplished by standard Friedel-Crafts methods but, like Waylander, I am a big fan of polyphosphoric acid (PPA). The cyclohexyl series **b** (R = *c*-C<sub>6</sub>H<sub>11</sub>) is likely to lead to ketoacid **5b**. 
[image]

1) C. F. H. Allen and H. B. Johnson, [*Organic Synthesis, Coll. Vol. 4*, 804, **1963**](http://orgsyn.org/Default.aspx).; Vol. *30*, 83, **1950**.